# How set up the Clickhandler for different Buttons?

Tags: gwt, onclick

i'm using gwt and want to create my own onClickHandler.
at the google docs i found a good example:

```js
public class HandlerExample extends Composite implements ClickHandler {
  private FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
  private Button b1 = new Button("Button 1");
  private Button b2 = new Button("Button 2");

  public HandlerExample() {
    initWidget(fp);
    fp.add(b1);
    fp.add(b2);
    b1.addClickHandler(this);
    b2.addClickHandler(this);
  }

  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // note that in general, events can have sources that are not Widgets.
    Widget sender = (Widget) event.getSource();

    if (sender == b1) {
      // handle b1 being clicked
    } else if (sender == b2) {
     // handle b2 being clicked
   }
  }
}
```

but in my project the clickhandlermethod is out of the file with the buttons. Is there a way to handle buttons with different function with one handler?

greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class HandlerExample extends Composite {
  private FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
  private Button b1 = new Button("Button 1");
  private Button b2 = new Button("Button 2");

  public HandlerExample() {
    initWidget(fp);
    fp.add(b1);
    fp.add(b2);
  }

  public List< HandlerRegistration > addClickHandlerToAllButtons( ClickHandler handler ) {
    List< HandlerRegistration > handlerRegistrations = new ArrayList< HandlerRegistration >();
    handlerRegistrations.add( b1.addClickHandler( handler ) );
    handlerRegistrations.add( b2.addClickHandler( handler ) );

    return handlerRegistrations;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement [HasClickHandlers](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasClickHandlers.html) instead. Then you can set your implementations of [ClickHanlder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ClickHandler.html) from outside your widget code.

Do you need to have different `ClickHandler`'s for different buttons? If so, then maybe you could just have `public`/`protected` methods to set `ClickHandler`'s for each button.